# Error when adding 'javax.json:javax.json-api:1.1' dependency for a project

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I made a very little pure JAVA project with Intellij, I needed some libraries, so I declared them as dependencies in Maven pom.xml file :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dongliu</groupId>
        <artifactId>requests</artifactId>
        <version>4.14.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

This worked well.

Now I want to reuse my code into a very new android project.
I am using android studio 3.0.1

I declared the dependencies this time in app/build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.econocom.seboxmonitoringapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
//    compileOptions {
//        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
//        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
//    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'net.dongliu:requests:4.14.1'      <-- OK
    implementation 'javax.json:javax.json-api:1.1'    <-- not OK
    implementation 'org.glassfish:javax.json:1.1'     <-- not OK
}
```

For 2 of the 3 dependencies, it does not work :

I got this error :

```
Error:com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
```

I tried to add compileOptions as suggested in another Stackoverflow question :

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

But now, I have another error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input  etc...
```

My project/build.gradle contains :

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I did all that on an a very new project : I just have choosen in android studio :

> "new project" -> give application name -> phone and Tablet (API 16) -> Empty activity.

I do not have added any code yet.  I just modified the app/build.gradle

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: I have got a similar, maybe the same problem: I tried making all glassfish dependencies comileOnly dependencies in my library code and added the compile dependency at the top most project, i.e. the android app. When I add the dependency on glassfish, I get an error "Program type already present: javax.json.Json", when I remove the dependency on glassfish, everything compiles fine, but when I use Json at runtime, the app closes and I get the error message "Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found". I somehow get the feeling, glassfish just doesn't work with Android, am I right?